# SQL "Where In" for empty subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, where-in

I have the following query, where the intention is to show each record with the time until the next record

Data:

```
gid         time                name
1010883478  29/03/2016 0:00:02  John
1010883527  29/03/2016 0:00:04  John
1010883578  29/03/2016 0:00:06  John
```

SQL:

```
  SELECT A.[gid]
       ,A.[time]
       ,A.[name]
       ,(B.[time] - A.[time]) as timeTilNext
  FROM [location] A CROSS JOIN [location] B 
  WHERE B.[gid] IN (
      SELECT MIN(C.[gid]) 
      FROM [location] C 
      WHERE C.[gid] > A.[gid] AND C.[name] = A.[name] )
  ORDER BY A.[gid]
```

Current Output:

```
gid         time                    name    timeTilNext
1010883478  2016-03-29 00:00:02.000 John    1900-01-01 00:00:02.000
1010883527  2016-03-29 00:00:04.000 John    1900-01-01 00:00:02.000
```

Expected Output:

```
gid         time                    name    timeTilNext
1010883478  2016-03-29 00:00:02.000 John    1900-01-01 00:00:02.000
1010883527  2016-03-29 00:00:04.000 John    1900-01-01 00:00:02.000
1010883578  2016-03-29 00:00:06.000 John    -1 (or whatever)
```

However, it does not show a record for the highest [gid] for a given [name] (only the second highest).

I'm hoping for the highest [gid] to show -1 for timeTilNext, to indicate that there is no more events.

Any ideas about how to modify my query?

Comment: please post some sample data and the expected result. What version of SQL Server are you using ?

Comment: Unsure why the downvotes and why answers were removed?

Comment: @Zeophlite, your `expected` section of the question is confusing. If I understood it correctly, your `output` section should be labelled as `current output` and show two rows as it is now. The `expected` section should show exactly what you expect, i.e. all three rows, not just one row. Maybe this confusion was the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov , good point, I've updated the question to reflect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 you can use [`LEAD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh213125.aspx) window function to get the value of the "next" row.

```
DECLARE @location TABLE ([gid] int, [time] datetime, [name] varchar(50));

INSERT INTO @location ([gid], [time], [name]) VALUES
(1010883478, '2016-03-29 00:00:02', 'John'),
(1010883527, '2016-03-29 00:00:04', 'John'),
(1010883578, '2016-03-29 00:00:06', 'John');

SELECT 
    A.[gid]
    ,A.[time]
    ,A.[name]
    ,LEAD(A.[time]) OVER(PARTITION BY A.[name] ORDER BY A.[gid]) AS NextTime
    ,ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second, A.[time], 
        LEAD(A.[time]) OVER(PARTITION BY A.[name] ORDER BY A.[gid])), -1) AS SecondsTillNext
FROM @location A
ORDER BY A.[gid];
```

**Result**

```
+------------+-------------------------+------+-------------------------+-----------------+
|    gid     |          time           | name |        NextTime         | SecondsTillNext |
+------------+-------------------------+------+-------------------------+-----------------+
| 1010883478 | 2016-03-29 00:00:02.000 | John | 2016-03-29 00:00:04.000 |               2 |
| 1010883527 | 2016-03-29 00:00:04.000 | John | 2016-03-29 00:00:06.000 |               2 |
| 1010883578 | 2016-03-29 00:00:06.000 | John | NULL                    |              -1 |
+------------+-------------------------+------+-------------------------+-----------------+
```

If the "next" row is not available, `LEAD` would return `NULL`. You can use `ISNULL()` to replace it with some non-null value if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
*,-1 as 'time until next ' from location t1
where time=(select max(time) from location t2 where t1.name=t2.name) b
```

Comment: Could you update this to match the headings in the question?

Comment: This matches with headings of your question,only change is tablename,i have changed it now

Answer (score 0):

SELECT A.gid,A.name,A.time,
(
    (SELECT MIN(B.time) FROM [location]  B WHERE B.time>A.time AND B.name=A.name)
    -
    A.time
) as timeTilNext

FROM [location]  A